# Enable Virtualisation on Asus P5QL Pro

Tags: virtualization, bios

I recently ran into a problem similar to [“CPU is not compatible with 64 bit mode” error trying to install Windows 7 (64 Bit) on VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85568/virtual-box-installation-to-install-window-764-bit). I am running 64 bit ubuntu 10.04 ltsand I can't install windows 7 64bit in Virtualbox 4.1.8

The answer suggests:

> Enable the virtualization setting inside your computer BIOS. After that, you may install 64 Bit Windows 7 inside VirtualBox.

I have looked under Advanced> Cpu configuration and can't find an option to enable virtualisation. 
I have the Intel Core 2 Quad CPU Q8200 
I Just checked the intel site and that processor does not support virtualisation. Does this mean that it is not possible to run windows 7 64 bit at all?

Comment: Did you try the other answer? What BIOS do you have?

Comment: I have the default Bios, I haven't changed since I got the motherboard.How can I check?

Comment: Try with for example Microsoft Virtual PC. It (if I remember correctly) should work fine even without virtualization extensions. (or it could be that that's only for 32bit on 64bit)

Comment: @AndrejaKo That's for, as you mentioned, only 32-bit guest on a 64-bit host.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the BIOS and enable virtualization in the CPU Configuration menu. Look for INTEL VT option and enable it.

If there is no INTEL VT option in your BIOS it may mean that your CPU does not have a vt flag and therefore is not capable of allowing full hypervisor virtualization. In that case you should install your Vbox guest 'para-virtualized' which cannot be 64-bit although 32-bit will work. In this case just say to yourself: "yeargh... who needs 64-bit anyway?"

If your BIOS doesn't allow you to enable virtualization, then simply install a 32-bit OS in VirtualBox. As documented [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#32-bit_vs_64-bit) the relative benefit of 64-bit processing is not platform-wide. Besides, compared to the OS you are installing as a VM guest, the true power of your PC resides in the 64-bit version of Ubuntu you have running as the primary OS.

Comment: I start the computer hold down del.Then go to Advanced > Cpu configuration and I don't see INTEL VT

Comment: Do note that in general not having Intel VT, Intel VT-x, Intel VT-d or similar in BIOS or UEFI does not necessarily mean that the hardware doesn't support the virtualization. It could that BIOS makers decided that users aren't going to need it and have removed the option to enable it. It happened to me and required some BIOS hacking.

Comment: Hmm seems a bit dodgy to hack your bios and definitely out of my knowledge level. \

Comment: @andrew, no problem, just go ahead and install 32-bit Windows para-virtualized in VirtualBox - it will work fine. You have 64bit capability in your Ubuntu host which is the shizniz anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Without Hardware Virtualization support, it's not possible to run 64-bit OS on a 32-bit host.

Comment: And what if your host is 64 bit? I don't think that comment is relevant to this particular situation.

Comment: You would still [need VT-x instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#64-bit) to run a 64-bit guest on an Intel processor @andrew